# LIFI VLC con JS

Tags: javascript, html, script

Estoy haciendo un código para enviar información por bits, es información LIFI que usa el flash del celular para enviar dicha información. He conseguido encender el flash desde la web con JS pero a la hora de enviar el mensaje tengo un error, ¿alguna idea de lo que puedo hacer?

El codigo es:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <div class="input-group mt-3 ml-auto mr-auto">
    <input id="msg" class="form-control" type="text" name="msg" placeholder="Type message here..." />
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button id="toggle" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
    </div>
<script>
//have a console on mobile
var consoleOutput = document.getElementById("console");
const log = function(msg){
    //  consoleOutput.innerText = `${consoleOutput.innerText}\n${JSON.stringify(msg)}`;
    document.getElementById("console").innerText = msg;
    console.log(msg);
}

//Test browser support
const SUPPORTS_MEDIA_DEVICES = 'mediaDevices' in navigator;

if (SUPPORTS_MEDIA_DEVICES) {
  //Get the environment camera (usually the second one)
  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {
  
    const cameras = devices.filter((device) => device.kind === 'videoinput');

    if (cameras.length === 0) {
      log('No camera found on this device.');
    }
    const camera = cameras[cameras.length - 1];

    // Create stream and get video track
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: {
        deviceId: camera.deviceId,
        facingMode: ['environment', 'user'],
        height: {ideal: 1080},
        width: {ideal: 1920}
      }
    }).then(stream => {
      const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];

      //Create image capture object and get camera capabilities
      const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track)
imageCapture.getPhotoCapabilities().then(capabilities => {
 
        //let there be light!
        var isTorchOn  = false;
        const btn = document.querySelector('.switch');
        // if (capabilities.torch){
          btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            isTorchOn = !isTorchOn;
            log("El flash esta encendido?: " + isTorchOn)
            try{
                track.applyConstraints({
                advanced: [{torch: isTorchOn}]
              });
            } catch(err){
                    log(err);
            }
          });

        const btn2 = document.querySelector('.switchOff');
        if (!capabilities.torch){
            log("Precione habilitar y encender");
        }
          btn2.addEventListener('click', function(){
            try{
                track.applyConstraints({
                advanced: [{torch: false}]
              });
            } catch(err){
                    log(err);
            }
          });

      });
    }).catch(log);
  }).catch(log);
  
const msg = document.getElementById("msg");
const button = document.getElementById("toggle");
let interval = null;
button.onclick = () => {

  if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
    }
    const seq = [];
    ["\x02", ...msg.value, "\n", "\x03"].forEach(c => seq.push(...encode(c.charCodeAt(0))));
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (!seq.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
        } else if (seq.shift()) {
          try{
            track.applyConstraints({
                advanced: [{torch: isTorchOn}]
              });
            } catch(err){
                    log(err);
          }
        } else {
          try{
                track.applyConstraints({
                advanced: [{torch: false}]
              });
            } catch(err){
                    log(err);
            }
        }
    }, 50);

    function parity(val) {
    val = val ^ (val >> 1);
    val = val ^ (val >> 2);
    val = val ^ (val >> 4);
    return val & 1;
}

function encode(char) {
    const bits = [1];
    for (var i = 0x80; i > 0; i >>= 1) {
        bits.push(char & i ? 1 : 0);
    }
    bits.push(parity(char));
    bits.push(0);
    return bits;
}}}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="switch">Encender / Apagar</button> - 
    <button class="switchOff">Apagar</button>
    <h2>
    Console output
    </h2>
    <div id="console">Precione habilitar y encender</div>
</body></html>
```

Cuando haces clic en encender / apagar, el flash se enciende, pero necesito que cuando un usuario ingrese un mensaje o un número en el cuadro de texto, se encienda una secuencia al presionar aceptar. Cabe aclarar que este programa solo funciona en Chrome